# How can I serialize/deserialize SQLAlchemy.Column object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I searched around and couldn't find an answer, forgive me if I missed something obvious. Any pointers will be helpful. :)

The issue is around the serialization of `sqlalchemy.Column` object. I'm representing a database table in the below class

```
from sqlalchemy import Column

Class Table:
    name: Optional[str] = None
    columns: Optional[list[Column]] = None
```

I need to serialize the Table class object and that means both name and `columns` attributes must be serializable. However, the problem lies with serializing `columns`. Is there any way we can do this reliably?

And we cannot use Python's pickle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that my approach is optimal, but I would think about somethink like that:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

# Typo Class -> class, also we want to use e.g. pydantic to have a nice serializable model
class Table(BaseModel):
    
    # We need this to be able to have sqlalchemy.Column in our model 
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        
    name: Optional[str] = None
    columns: Optional[list[Column]] = None
```

And then you can use e.g. json module to serialize your objects:

```
import json

t = Table()
json.dumps(t, default=str)
```

Hope this will help